# continue userActivity: NSUserActivity - Identify it is from callkit or contacts

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, nsuseractivity

I have implemented callkit in my project.

So when I report incoming call there is video button. so according to this answer [user102008's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403483/how-are-the-cxstartcallaction-isvideo-property-and-native-video-button-used-in/43487523#43487523) When user tap on video button

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

Delegate method called with intent type `INStartVideoCallIntent`

But There is other case where the same delegate method called with `INStartVideoCallIntent`  when user tap video button from contacts app

See the image 
[image]

Now the problem is I am not able to identify how can I differentiate both actions Callkit video button and contacts video button.

Any Help or suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance